# What are the benefits of using the fields option when querying in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

```
SomeCollection.find({}, { fields: { exerciseId: 1} })
```

After running a time test, it looks like this query takes longer than just `find()` without any arguments. Are there any benefits of limiting the field? I guess, it will use less local memory but when is that worth it?

Comment: Could you share the code you used for the time test?  Less memory on client, lesser data sent over the wire are some obvious  advantages..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience the benefits of using `fields` on the *client* are limited. But you should absolutely use it when defining your publications on the *server* for two reasons:

1. Security: hide fields the client has no business seeing, especially fields about other users
2. Performance: fewer fields means fewer bytes on the wire. Especially important when a subscription includes many documents.

Comment: I should have added: use the websocket inspector in your browser to watch the websocket traffic to/from your client to better understand what's happening under the hood. The chrome websocket inspector is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

The benefit is that it becomes less reactive, which you can benefit from in `Tracker.autorun` and when you use `observe` or `observeChanges`.

**EDIT**

I'm not 100% sure about `Tracker.autorun`.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly specifying is indeed saving memory, sends less data over the wire and might give you a small performance boost. Another important use for it is as a security measure. Imagine that you want your client-side to subscribe to the Users collection, but you don't want the user's password or any other field containing sensitive information to be visible on the client. In that case, when you're publishing the collection, you'd do it this way:

```
Meteor.publish('secureUsers', function() {
  if(!this.userId) return null;
  return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, 
    {fields: 
      {
        someNonSensitiveField: 1, /* avatar information, for example */
        otherNonSensitiveField: 1
      }
    }
  );
});
```

This way only the specified fields will be included in the collection objects, leaving out the other data, which might be sensitive. Another approach is to specify which fields are sensitive and exclude them explicitly.

HTH!

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that this feature was developed as an optimization technique. Security aspect is secondary, at best.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I'm quite sure security is the top priority in most frameworks, as well as in Meteor.

Comment: @PeppeL-G: well, this one is a feature of mongodb. Meteor just exposes it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I see your point, but I disagree. Meteor made the choice to expose it, and I'm quite sure security, and not optimization, was the main reason for it.

Comment: @PeppeL-G: I disagree. Common sense was the reason for it. If mongodb is your the only database, and you don't expose as much functionality as you can, you're a shitty framework :)

Comment: All right gentlemen, I appreciate your comments! I have edited my answer and I hope it is now more agreeable and brings more value to the question.